# Google Guice + generics: Is there some magic behind the curtains?

Tags: java, generics, guice

It seems to me that Guice implementation is doing some very tricky things when dealing with generics. It looks like it *knows at runtime* about generic types used at compile time. Let's see a simple example:

```
@Inject
public void Bar(Provider<Foo> genericInjector){
...
```

At runtime Guice will inject a correct implementation of `Provider` here (i.e. the one that provides `Foo` instances). But from what I know, generic types are *erased* at runtime (see: [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) ). So all that Guice really sees at runtime is:

```
@Inject
public void Bar(Provider genericInjector){
....
```

So how is it possible that Guice knows which implementation of `Provider` to inject?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, type erasure doesn't erase *everything*. You can still get the types of fields, parameters etc. The `Provider<Foo>` information *is* still present at execution time. See [`Method.getGenericParameterTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29) for example.

What *isn't* preserved is the type information about specific objects. For example, if I write:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
showType(list);

...


public static void showType(List<?> list)
{
    // ???
}
```

There's no way that can work out that it's an `ArrayList<String>` because the object doesn't have that information any more.

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for a *lot* more information.

Comment: Allright! I believe that's exactly what Inerdial meant but it's much more clearer for me in your answer. I will check this out and if you're right, I'll grant you correct answer :).

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misconception that the way type erasure works is that the compiler essentially removes angle brackets and what's inside them and then acts as if the source was Java 1.4. This is not the case.

Generic parameters don't get erased from method signatures – method signatures are "compile-time". Generic parameters don't exist in "runtime" constructs – you can't tell what type parameters a given object was instantiated with.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I still don't get it. What do you mean by saying that: "method signatures are compile time"? Is it that generic parameters aren't erased from method signatures at runtime and are erased from everywhere else? I've never heard about such distinction :(.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk: [Angelika Langer's FAQ on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3) will probably explain this better than I could ever hope to.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is in fact very userful link and updated answer is more clear. Unfortunately all I can get you is one upvote :(. Jon was a little more precise.